# rtld-Rules:40: *** This makefile is a subroutine of elf/Makefile not to be used directly. when building glibc

Tags: cygwin, glibc

I'm trying to build glibc on cygwin but I keep on getting this error

```
[ALL  ]      rtld-Rules:40: *** This makefile is a subroutine of elf/Makefile not to be used directly.  Stop.
[ALL  ]      make[4]: Leaving directory '/build/src/glibc-2.38/elf'
[ERROR]      make[3]: *** [Makefile:1315: /build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/build/build-libc/multilib/elf/rtld-libc.a] Error 2
[ERROR]      make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ALL  ]      make[3]: Leaving directory '/build/src/glibc-2.38/elf'
[ERROR]      make[2]: *** [Makefile:484: elf/subdir_lib] Error 2
[ALL  ]      make[2]: Leaving directory '/build/src/glibc-2.38'
[ERROR]      make[1]: *** [Makefile:9: all] Error 2
[ALL  ]      make[1]: Leaving directory '/build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/build/build-libc/multilib'
```

I'm building it through crossingtool-ng.

Here's the configuration it used:

```
/build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/src/glibc/configure --prefix=/usr --build=x86_64-build_pc-cygwin --host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --cache-file=/build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/build/build-libc/multilib/config.cache --without-cvs --disable-profile --without-gd --with-headers=/x-tools/}x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include --disable-debug --disable-sanity-checks --enable-kernel=6.5.5 --with-__thread --with-tls --enable-shared --enable-add-ons=no
```

Comment: You need to subscribe to the cygwin mailing list and ask your question there. Visit the cygwin.com website.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm already subscribed to it but how do I send the question to it?

Comment: Just use `cygwin@cygwin.com` as the To address in an email. Use plain text mode, not html mode.

Comment: Let me clearfy it. How Do I send to to cygwin what do I use? How do I use it. Do I send it from the cygwin command line or through the site.

Comment: Use your email app, e.g. gmail, outlook, thunderbird, etc. Put `c6gwin@cygwin.com` as the recipient.

Comment: Just use your regular email  app. Fill in the recipients  as above. Use a descriptive subject and describe your problem in the body of the email. Use plain text mode instead of fancy html format,